# Algorithm that simplifies if statements

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a series of if statements that fills an array `myArray` at a position that depends on the range (multiples of `y`) in which value `x` lies in.

I was wondering if there's a simpler way to add `off` to the correct Array element based on the value of `x`. `x` is a function of the current `column` and `row` that I iterate over.

```
for(int i = 0; i< rows; i++)
{
 for(int j = 0; j< cols; j++)
 { 
  x = getX(i, j);
  if(x < y * 1  &&  x => 0)
   MyArray[0] += off;
  if(x < y * 2  &&  x >= y * 1)
   MyArray[1] += off;
  if(x < y * 3  &&  x >= y * 2)
   MyArray[2] += off;
  if(x < y * 4  &&  x >= y * 3)
   MyArray[3] += off;
  if(x < y * 5  &&  x >= y * 4)
   MyArray[4] += off;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that one condition out of the two in each if statement has an '=' (<= or >=). You can then try something like:

```
int ratio = x/y;
if (ratio >= 0 && ratio < 5)
    MyArray[ratio] += off;
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the > to >=